# Google Maps v3 block map interaction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a Polyline editor, just like [the one from Google Drawings Library](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_DrawingTools_deleteAll.html). (for specific reasons, i can't use that one)

It works on the same principle. Start with a point, then for each click add new points and make the polyline.

On the editor from Google Drawings Library, while you are editing a polyline, you're mouse can't interact with other items from the map.

Inspecting with firebug, i see that they have an overlay of 20000000 z-index inside the map.

[image: Overlay while editing with Google Drawings Library]

Is there any way of creating the same overlay for my map using default Google Maps functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) inside the `overlayMouseTarget`-pane with the same size as the map and a draw-method that updates the position of the overlay. You may do the same.

Comment: Exactly what i was hoping for :D